# how to debug the child values in parent to child query using for loop

Tags: apex, debug

```
 List<Account> accs=[select id,name,Phone,
                           (select id,lastname,firstname,email 
                            from contacts) 
                     from account];

for(Account aa:accs){ 
            System.debug(aa.id);
            System.debug(aa.name);
            System.debug(aa.phone);
 }
 for(Contact con:accs.contacts){

 }
```

In first for loop it does not any error while second loop is giving error. I got parent values in first for loop.But i want child values too. Can any one help me please.

Thanks and regards

Kumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for(Contact con:accs.contacts){
```

`accs` is a list of account records, so `accs.contacts` isn't valid. You need to nest the contacts loop inside of the other one so that you're working with the account records themselves, not the list.

```
   for(Account aa:accs){ 
       System.debug(aa.id);
       System.debug(aa.name);
       System.debug(aa.phone);

       for(Contact con:aa.contacts){
           System.debug(con.firstname);
       }
   }
```

While I'm at it, you might want to consider some more descriptive variable names, things like `aa` and `accs` don't make for easy reading later down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this

```
for(Account aa:accs){ 
            System.debug(aa.id);
            System.debug(aa.name);
            System.debug(aa.phone);

    for(Contact con:aa.contacts){

    }
 }
```

we use nested for loop to get inner query records.

or if you want to get only first parent record then

```
for(Account aa:accs){ 
            System.debug(aa.id);
            System.debug(aa.name);
            System.debug(aa.phone);
 }
 if(accs != null && accs.size() > 0)
 for(Contact con:accs[0].contacts){

 }
```